# How to isolate a gitlab runner to process specific environment or stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to use gitlab runners for our builds and our deployment to QA. Can I set up a second runner that ONLY does deployments, or just a specific environment? I don't see a way to do this. (Gitlab.com/private runners)

Answer (score 1):

Found it. This can be achieved using [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#tags). CI runners can be configured to run only jobs that have specific tags, and tags can be applied to jobs.